# is there a way to pass parameter of flask api to my python code

Tags: python, api, flask

hello am trying to create flask api where user input the vaue and I will use that value to process my python code
here is the code

`

```
app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

class Users(Resource):
    @app.route('/users/<string:name>/')
    def hello(name):
        namesource = request.args.get('name')
        return "Hello {}!".format(name)

print(namesource)  # here am trying to get the sitring/value in name source but i can't because it no       variable defines

api.add_resource(Users, name='users')
# For Running our Api on Localhost
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

`

am trying to expect that i get that value/String outside of the function of api flask

Comment: You have this a little backwards. In your example, you cannot access `namesource` outside of the scope of the `hello` function. The solution here is to access the rest of the code you wish to run from within the scope of the `hello` function. So bundle the rest of the code you wish to run in a function, and call that function from within `hello`, passing in the variable `namesource` as an argument.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to access the variable `namesource` outside of the function `hello`.
You can't do that.
You can access the variable `name` outside of the function `hello` because it is a parameter of the function. You can fix it by making a global variable.

```py
app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

namesource = None

class Users(Resource):
    @app.route('/users/&lt;string:name&gt;/')
    def hello(name):
        global namesource
        namesource = request.args.get('name')
        return "Hello {}!".format(name)

print(namesource)

api.add_resource(Users, name='users')
# For Running our Api on Localhost
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: I have tried that but i get the none value

Comment: That is because you are printing `namesource` before assigning it. You can give it a default starting value, or print it inside your `hello` function (recommended).